# Unstable google custom search API top results

Tags: python, google-custom-search

I noticed an issue with google custom search API: the most of requests are returning 3 top searches as below (search string is "tesla.com"):

1. 'https://twitter.com/tesla'
2. 'https://twitter.com/tesla?lang=ar'
3. 'https://twitter.com/elonmusk'

but sometimes first search results changes to:

1. 'https://twitter.com/tesla/status/1026912973120462848'
2. 'https://twitter.com/tesla'
3. 'https://twitter.com/tesla?lang=ca'

Google Custom Search engine is configured to search on pages at "*.twitter.com" domain only.

Do you know how to explain its behaviour ?

Comment: Are you using one these client libraries?  [Google API Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library)

Comment: I am using python **googleapiclient** package to connect with cse API

Comment: Do you see the same varying results on the public URL that is available in the google api config app?  I just created a test custom search url and I tried the search a few times and the top results are the same.  I suppose the results may vary depending when when the indexes get updated.  just a theory, I dont know. [test twitter custom search url](https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=010915813110318285450:acwwu11i4dk)

Comment: also tested and results are not varying on google api config app, I can see sometimes results  varying only when using api, maybe just due to index changes